# Change uint8_t* to char*?

Tags: c++, c, casting, signed, unsigned-char

I have an API which requests a `char*`, this is my API function:

```
CANMessage(unsigned _id,  const char* _data, char _len = 8)
```

More information available here: https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/mbed-os-api-doxy/classmbed_1_1_c_a_n_message.html

I would like to call this function from within another function, but I am getting confused about `const char*` and casting. I want to call this function from function `foo()`, like so:

```
void foo(unsigned int id, /*???*/ data, char len) {
    CANMessage(id, data, len)
}
```

So I need to pass id, data and len to function foo. My problem is that the `data` coming in is a `uint8_t` type. I got a vector of `uint8_t`, where the address of the first element is the one I need to pass:

```
vector<uint8_t> dta;
```

Which I tried to pass as `&dta[0]`: `foo(idNo, &dta[0], length)`

With the foo function as so:

```
void foo(unsigned int id, uint8_t* data, char len) {
    CANMessage(id, (char*)data, len)
}
```

But I get "Argument of type std::uint8_t * is incompatible with parameter of type char*

How do I pass it as `const char*` when function `foo`, which calls it, accepts `uint8_t*`?

Please note I can't change types, dta has to stay `vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: Note that `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned` (up to your implementation) and in both case `char` is a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: Generally you should treat any C-style cast as a red flag that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please copy-paste the *full* and *complete error output, including any possible informational notes.

Comment: Please, provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). In general, you should have no problem with casting to `const char *`.

Comment: Why don't you try to `CANMessage(id, reintepret_cast<char*>(&data[0]), len) `. In fact there is no binary difference between `char` and `uint8_t` data types. Both are 8-bits, so casting is safe if you working with arrays of characters or some RGBA pixmaps. Off cause if you are working with integer values, i.e. you have something like `if(a[i] > b[i])` you'd better not to cast.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dta.data())` and `static_cast<char>(dta.size())` could do it.

Comment: What is `uint_8`?

Comment: @Eljay Good catch. :-) Eskey: Your code does not match the error message.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem with your example (with missing parts to make it complete): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b54a11a5b0a341f

Comment: @eerorika I was only able to reproduce it inside a C++98 mbed compiler, I tried my problem in visual studio and it was fine, with no errors, I didn't mention it as just the small mbed environment can check it using that online compiler. I ended up taking a different approach, my foo function now takes char* and I cast to char* when I call instead (char*)&dta[0]. CANMessage can therefore just use the foo's char*. I was able to solve my problem, and luckily char* is just a buffer so casting should be harmless, per Michael's explanation, luckily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::uint8_t` ιs equal to `unsigned char`.

This is different from plain char or signed char, but all of them are 8 bit, therefore casting would techically work.

It's common that many functions that would otherwise need a "buffer" have a `char*` in their definition instead of the proper `unsigned char*`. Therefore, casting would most probably be harmless.

In the case that the function actually wants characters but not a buffer, then you have a problem because the types are different, and whether you will have an issue or not is undefined.

Comment: "`std::uint8_t` is equal to `unsigned char`" Is this required? Could it legally be an extended integer type?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if `std::uint8_t` exists then `unsigned char` must be an unsigned 8-bit type. If `CHAR_BIT > 8` then uint8_t can't exist

Comment: @phuclv I agree that if `std::uint8_t` is defined, necessarily `unsigned char` is a compatible candidate for it. What I'm wondering is if it's required that `std::uint8_t` actually be `unsigned char`. I don't see why an implementation would do otherwise, even if another `unsigned` 8 bit integer type is provided. You might as well just define it to be `unsigned char` but I'm not sure if it *has* to.

Comment: `std::uint8_t` is a defined type, `unsigned char` is a built in type. Defined types must somehow be defined with the aid of build in types. If not using `unsigned char`, what else could be used?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis It could be an [extended integer type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental#def:extended_signed_integer_type), they qualify as a fundamental integer type. For example, my compiler might have a `__unsigned_byte` type or something for reasons I can't imagine. Edit : There's also `char8_t` that has the same size, signedness and alignment as `unsigned char` since C++20.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Okay I see. It must be a buffer as I have already successfully used casting to char to send a message using the can protocol. Preferably the API would be unsigned char*, unfortunately this isn't the case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Not having 8-bit `char` types but having fixed-width 8-bit extended `int` types would be somewhat *strange*.  But yeah, it seems legal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in an environment where `std::uint8_t` is available, the `char` types must be max 8 bits, but just to make sure you're not on a machine with 7 bit char's, add a `static_assert`.

[reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) the `uint8_t*` to `const char*` and [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) the size (`size_t`) of the vector to `char`.

```
void foo(unsigned _id, const std::vector<uint8_t>& dta) {
    static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8, "Strange char");

    CANMessage(
        _id,
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dta.data()),
        static_cast<char>(dta.size())
    );
}
```

Comment: Both C and C++ require that all flavors of `char` be at least 8 bits. That comes from the definition of `CHAR_BIT` in `<limits.h>` which comes into C++ through `<climits>`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't know of any systems where `char`s have less than 8 bits myself, but there are plenty of other discussions here on SO mentioning both 6 and 7 bit char historical machines. One can probably disregard those Today though :-) ... but even if both `uint8_t` and `char` have 8 bits - they are not necessarily bit compatible as  François Andrieux points out.